Pausing and Resuming Simulation in AnyLogic - Issue with runSimulation()
I am simulating a port environment and during the simulation I need to PAUSE the model temporaly to get a boolean response from a code then CONTINUE the simulation. This code is located on “On Release” inside a “ResourcePool” block. The information required is taken from the resource agent. Testing the code while pauseSimulation() works as expected, I'm unable to resume the simulation using runSimulation(). What can I add to the code to resume the simulation after the pause?
Here is a screenshot  of my Resource Agent and Code location:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Here is the code that I am trying to implement:
if (unit.timesUsed >= 4) {

    //pause the simulation
    pauseSimulation();
    machineType = "Balança";
    
    if (unit.GA_balanca() == true) {
        //continue the simulation
        runSimulation();
    
        if (newData_balanca.before(date())) {
    
            //change the manteinance data
            data_balanca = date();
            newData_balanca = addToDate(data_balanca, HOUR, 2);
    
            //manteinance
            maintenance.startTask(unit);
            unit.qtd_mant ++;
    
            //data output
            unit.data_mant = date();
            insertInto(maintenance_data)
            .columns(maintenance_data.machine_type, maintenance_data.when_out, maintenance_data.times_out)
            .values(unit.type, unit.data_mant, unit.qtd_mant)
            .execute();
    
            //0 times
            unit.timesUsed = 0;
    
    
            } else {
            }
        } else {
    }
    


pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other users on SOF :)

Thank you!I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm code that will receive info about my resource utilization.Once a trigger, located inside the ResourcePool, calls this code, the simulation needs to be paused so the code can analyze the current state and give the proper answer to allow or not the maintenance of the resource.Another thing is that I have 6 types of machines running at the same time.So it needs to be developed while the model isn't running, although the trigger may be activated twice and generate an error.With the GA response I need to resume the simulation automatically

If your simulation is paused, you cannot un-pause it via code. It is paused so no more code can be executed...
All you can do is to have a button with runSimulation() and click it. Or click the default "Run" button in the bottom left of the model window.
BUT: you never need to un-pause a model automatically. You only ever pause a model to review something visually, then click "Run" again. For anything else (including "to get a boolean response from a code"), you can do that without pausing it.
